# HTML+CSS Gallery

Tags: html, css

Someone will tell me why: hover does not detect the right child only treats the whole as one element, even though I've distinguished more children and changes me the same screen all the time, how to fix it?
I need to do it when I try to mouse on an element ".image" big element switch z-index for the right one.

Online code: https://jsfiddle.net/2zr6pj9u/1/

HTML

```
<section class="galery">
    <div class="small-img">
        <div class="image" id="numer1"><img src="https://images5.alphacoders.com/322/thumb-1920-322588.jpg" alt="obraz"></div>
        <div class="image" id="numer2"><img src="http://www.banktapet.pl/pictures/2012/0615/1/blue-ocean-sea-1600x900-wallpaper-531986.jpg" alt="obraz"></div>
        <div class="image" id="numer3"><img src="http://wrzutka.pl/files/walls/d3f32e12/x.jpg" alt="obraz"></div>
        <div class="image" id="numer4"><img src="https://a-static.besthdwallpaper.com/rocky-ocean-tapeta-3957_L.jpg" alt="obraz"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="big-img">
        <div class="big-image" id="nr1"><img src="https://images5.alphacoders.com/322/thumb-1920-322588.jpg" alt="obraz"></div>
        <div class="big-image" id="nr2"><img src="http://www.banktapet.pl/pictures/2012/0615/1/blue-ocean-sea-1600x900-wallpaper-531986.jpg" alt="obraz"></div>
        <div class="big-image" id="nr3"><img src="http://wrzutka.pl/files/walls/d3f32e12/x.jpg" alt="obraz"></div>
        <div class="big-image" id="nr4"><img src="https://a-static.besthdwallpaper.com/rocky-ocean-tapeta-3957_L.jpg" alt="obraz"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.galery {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.small-img {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.big-img {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.big-image {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#nr1 {
  z-index: 1;
}
#nr2 {
  z-index: 2;
}
#nr3 {
  z-index: 3;
}
#nr4 {
  z-index: 4;
}
.small-img:first-child:hover ~ .big-img #nr1 {
  z-index: 5;
}
.small-img:nth-child(2):hover ~ .big-img #nr2 {
  z-index: 5;
}
.small-img:nth-child(3):hover ~ .big-img #nr3 {
  z-index: 5;
}
.small-img:last-child:hover ~ .big-img #nr4 {
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: I don’t really understand what the problem is. Can you explain more in detail? :)

Comment: When i select small image from column on the left side, then big image from the right side, must show me this image in a larger window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this without using Javascript. The issue is outlined below.

There are two problems:

1. You have `:nth-child` on the wrong element. `nth-child` applies to the element you are targeting. In your code, you are always targeting the `.small-img` div NOT the `.image` div - which is what you want.

**CSS**

```
.small-img .image:first-child:hover ~ .big-img #nr1{
    z-index: 5;
}
.small-img .image:nth-child(2):hover ~ .big-img #nr2{
    z-index: 5;
}
.small-img .image:nth-child(3):hover ~ .big-img #nr3{
    z-index: 5;
}
.small-img .image:last-child:hover ~ .big-img #nr4{
    z-index: 5;
}
```

That's what you should have so you can target each `.image` child.

2. Here's the problem. Now that we target the correct child div (`.image`), we have no way in CSS to move outside of the parent div (`.small-img`), then target the sibling `.big-img` div. `big-img` div is NOT a direct sibling of the `.image` divs, so we can't target that.

## **Here's a solution if you want to update your markup:**

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 75%;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-areas: "small1 big" "small2 big" "small3 big" "small4 big";
}

.grid-container .small-image:nth-child(1) {
  background: yellow;
  grid-area: small1;
}

.grid-container .small-image:nth-child(1):hover~#limage-1 {
  z-index: 10;
}

.grid-container .small-image:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
  grid-area: small2;
}

.grid-container .small-image:nth-child(2):hover~#limage-2 {
  z-index: 10;
}

.grid-container .small-image:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: small3;
  background: blue;
}

.grid-container .small-image:nth-child(3):hover~#limage-3 {
  z-index: 10;
}

.grid-container .small-image:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: small4;
  background: purple;
}

.grid-container .small-image:nth-child(4):hover~#limage-4 {
  z-index: 10;
}

.grid-container .large-image {
  position: relative;
  grid-area: big;
}

.grid-container .large-image#limage-1 {
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 9;
}

.grid-container .large-image#limage-2 {
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

.grid-container .large-image#limage-3 {
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

.grid-container .large-image#limage-4 {
  background: purple;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="small-image" id="image-1"></div>
  <div class="small-image" id="image-2"></div>
  <div class="small-image" id="image-3"></div>
  <div class="small-image" id="image-4"></div>
  <div class="large-image" id="limage-1"></div>
  <div class="large-image" id="limage-2"></div>
  <div class="large-image" id="limage-3"></div>
  <div class="large-image" id="limage-4"></div>
</div>
```

Codepen
https://codepen.io/chrislafrombois/pen/gEbLRE

Comment: That I could do it, I would have to rebuild HTML and use css grid?

Comment: @DawidRuciński Yeah, you can rebuild your HTML and CSS to use the Grid. I've updated my answer and added a codepen so you can see it in action.